# Function template - Returning T based on input class? - C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have created a function template for loading my settings from a binary file.

```
template<class T> T LoadSettings(const std::string &fileName)
{
    // Load settings
    T settings;

    std::string filePath(LOCAL_FILE_DIR);
    filePath.append(fileName);

    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        if (!settings.ParseFromIstream(&file)) 
        {
            throw ExceptionMessage("Failed to parse TextureAtlasSettings");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw ExceptionMessage("Failed to open file");
    }

    return settings;
};
```

I would like to be able to invoke the function and return the appropriate settings class.

Coming from C# I would do the following.

```
MySettingsClass settings = LoadSettings<MySettingsClass>("FileName.bin");
```

How can I do the same thing in C++?

EDIT:

I should be more generic!

```
throw std::runtime_error("Failed to parse " + typeid(T).name());
```

Comment: Have you tried the same syntax?

Comment: It turns out I put the template declaration in the wrong place.  Which is why the same syntax didn't work for me.  I feel a bit foolish now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use this syntax in C++

```
MySettingsClass settings = LoadSettings<MySettingsClass>(std::string("FileName.bin"));
```

Comment: I didn't address anyone specifically. :)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. Even though explicitly calling the `std::string` constructor is not necessary, it does no harm at all and the rest of the answer is correct.

Comment: I upped the vote as it worked for me, after I worked out where I had gone wrong initially.

Answer (score 0):

```
 template<typename T> 
 T LoadSettings(const std::string& fileName)
 {
    // Load settings
    T settings;

    std::string filePath(LOCAL_FILE_DIR);
    filePath += fileName; 

     std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); 

     if (file && settings.ParseFromIstream(file)) 
     {    
           return settings;
     }
     throw std::runtime_error("Failed to parse TextureAtlasSettings");
 }
```

This should work, however you might want to consider writing an extraction operator foe your types T.

Comment: In what way is this different from OP's code (except some flow restructuring)?

Comment: std::runtime_error, += for std::string, file used in boolean expression, other than the OPs code was fine, the lack of difference just highlights that the OP should have tried it first.

Comment: Would the restructuring give me a specific error related to file opening and parsing?

Comment: _This should work, however you might want to consider writing an extraction operator foe your types T_. I've added an edit.  Is this along your lines of thinking?

Comment: not really, I really don't like RTTI and the typid stuff, and it's usage here is't so great, you might as well just have a .name() field on the `settings` types.